# Finish variance in Hours

Tags: ms-project, scheduling, ms-project-2010

How can I show the Finish variance column in hours and not days? I am working in MS project Pro 2010.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Options in the File tab.  Open Schedule.  Third option group down, you can change how duration is entered.  Choose hours.

Comment: You're welcome.